# How to run initdb for postgresql 9.2 on centos7?

Tags: postgresql, centos7

So,

My admin installed (don't know how) postgresql 9.2 (64 bit version) on a centos7 machine. The thing is I need to initalize the database so I should run something like:

```
service postgresql-9.2 initdb
```

but I get error:

```
The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl.
```

Did some search and people said that you should initialize via direct call to some script, but every given location does not exists in this CentOS 7 machine.

Like for example this location (yeah, it is for 9.3 and I use 9.2, but similar location does not exist anyway):

```
/usr/lib/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb
```

or this

```
/usr/pgsql-9.3/bin/postgresql93-setup initdb
```

I found out

```
/usr/lib64/pgsql
```

but this directory has only a bunch of  '*.so' files.

How the hell do I run initdb for postgresql 9.2 on centos7?

Comment: Did you try `which initdb`, `locate initdb`, or `find /usr -name initdb`? On Ubuntu it's in `/usr/lib/postgresql/9.2/bin/initdb`; I don't know where you might find it on Centos.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall', `which initdb` finds `/usr/bin/initdb`. However, I could not find any information on the internet that initdb could be located in this directory. Maybe admin installed in it in some weird way. Will try to reinstall just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it directly from postgres account

```
#su - postgres -c pg_ctl initdb
```

Answer (score 0):

Just installed the Postgresql 9.3 on Centos.

```
#cd /etc/init.d
#ls postgres*
```

and there is a posgresql-9.3 script

```
#./postgresql-9.3
```

gives you the options to run with and one of them is initdb

Comment: In this installation, is initdb a stand-alone, compiled executable?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to compile it? There should be the installation instructions for compiling it then. Look into the INSTALL or README in the source tree.

Comment: I'm curious about the differences. On my Ubuntu box, initdb is a compiled executable, which means that "which", "locate", or "find" should be able to find it. On your Centos installation, an "initdb" option to the postgresql-9.3 script could conceivably be an executable like on my box, another script, or part of a different compiled program.

Comment: On Ubuntu box, I would use pg_createcluster instead and its friends.